# Sending Mail through PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Here i have a problem when iam sending a mail.It is delevering properly but when iam trying designing the  message body with HTML tags it sending the same html tags to my email inbox.How can i overcome this please tell me.

Here the PHP code:

```
$to = "$email";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = '<!Doctype html><html><head><title>Confirm Link</title></head><body><div style="color:blue">Thank u for registering with us </div>
<div> Hi'.$name.' Please click the below link to activate your accont</div><div><a href="http://www.websitename.com/test2/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&name='.$name.'&mail='.$email.'">Active your account now</a></div> </body></html>';

$from = "abc@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

Here my deliverd email inbox message:
here designing not working it display same as my program code.Please help me.

Confirm LinkThank u for registering with us 
 HiSrinivas Please click the below link to activate your accont[Active your account now](http://www.websitename.com/test2/activation.php?id=57&name=Srinivas&mail=xyz@gmail.com)

Answer (score 4):

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

> Note:
>
> If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime.

[**Reference**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 0):

Send an HTML email:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are not setting the mail headers. Try this:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```